# how to do dead reckoning on column of table, postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a table looks like,

```
x    y
1    2
2    null
3    null
1    null
11   null
```

I want to fill the null value by conducting a rolling
function to apply y_{i+1}=y_{i}+x_{i+1} with sql as simple as possible (inplace)

so the expected result

```
x    y
1    2
2    4
3    7
1    8
11   19
```

implement in postgresql. I may encapsulate it in a window function, but the implementation of custom function seems always complex

Comment: @Houari I have tried window function with lag aggregation function, but that allows only one computation can not propagate the computation along the column

Comment: Hmm. smells like recursive...

Comment: Tables are unordered sets.  Is there an `id` column, or how else do you determine the order of rows?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over rows using a recursive CTE.  But in order to do so, you need a way to jump from row to row.  Here's an example using an ID column:

```
; with  recursive cte as
        (
        select  id
        ,       y
        from    Table1
        where   id = 1
        union all
        select  cur.id
        ,       prev.y + cur.x
        from    Table1 cur
        join    cte prev
        on      cur.id = prev.id + 1
        )
select  *
from    cte
;
```

You can see the query at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/479b6/3/0).  If you don't have an ID column, but you do have another way to order the rows, you can use `row_number()` to get an ID:

```
; with  recursive sorted as
        (
        -- Specify your ordering here.  This example sorts by the dt column.
        select  row_number() over (order by dt) as id
        ,       *
        from    Table1
        )
,       cte as
        (
        select  id
        ,       y
        from    sorted
        where   id = 1
        union all
        select  cur.id
        ,       prev.y + cur.x
        from    sorted cur
        join    cte prev
        on      cur.id = prev.id + 1
        )
select  *
from    cte
;
```

Here's the [SQL Fiddle link.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/818a0/3/0)

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH RECURSIVE t AS (
    select  x, y, 1 as rank from my_table where y is not null
  UNION ALL
    SELECT  A.x,  A.x+ t.y y , t.rank + 1 rank FROM t 
    inner join 
    (select row_number()  over () rank, x, y from my_table )  A   
    on t.rank+1  = A.rank 
)
SELECT x,y FROM t;
```

Comment: +1 This seems to [work nicely](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/818a0/5/0)  But how does `over ()` decide the order of rows?  Might it not for example label the row with `y is not null` as number 2, counting it double and omitting another row?